# Node.js exec git pull callback function argument incorrect

Tags: node.js, git, exec

I get confused. The error is null, why stderr is not null ? how about git pull command exit status code ?

Source code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('git pull --rebase origin master', {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    timeout: 0,
    maxBuffer: 200*1024,
    killSignal: 'SIGTERM',
    cwd: 'd:/code/puller',
    env: null
 },
 function(error, stdout, stderr)  {
   console.log('error', error);
   console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
   console.log('stderr: ', stderr);
   if (error !== null) {
  console.log("exec error", error);
 }
});
```

output:

```
error null
stdout:  Current branch master is up to date.

stderr:  From xx.com/user/puller
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: `git status` command It work well.

Answer (score 1):

`error` is used for node.js errors. For examplem when output in console is more than 200K node.js will crash with error `"Error: maxBuffer exceeded"`

`stderr` is for errors in console like you have

Comment: In the example. stderr text should be appeared at stdout.